# Android Studio Error at compiling - :app:preDexDebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc

```
:app:preDexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85) ...

Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
```

Hope you will find the error, cause I didn't although I have looked for an answer ...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues because the compiler didn't have enough memory to execute. Try to increase the memory for gradle or the build system you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In the Project SDK section, when you add an Android SDK you should provide the Java SDK and all my Android SDKs uses Java 8 as SDK so it create the class files with the wrong version even if the Project level is 1.7 (i don't know why, i supposed that everything was choosed by Project level).

Now i changed the SDK (the java version "1.x.0" part.)

[Here The Image  TO View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxTdo.png)

and it seems to compile fine.

The reason that worked before today was because my SDK was 1.8 and not Android API x